# make native code access java methods and data members

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am working on an android project with native code that is supposed to update a List and some other boolean variables in an object.

consider the following code

some java class in my code looks like:

```
 class ReturnObject
{
    boolean a, b;
    public List<String[]> listA;

}

public class foo
{
    public native void someFunction(ReturnObject returnObject);
}
```

and the native code looks like:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_androidtest_TestActivity_someFunction
  (JNIEnv * env, jobject jObj, jobject returnObject) {
    std::string f = "foo";
    // missing code here
    // returnObject.add(f) // add like in java
}
```

How can I set the values of the boolean variables?

and for the the List (**knowing my data in the native code are stored as `std::string`**), how can I invoke add(`String[] string`) method of the List class from native code?

Comment: _"How can I set the values of the boolean variables"_. Using `SetBooleanField`. _"how can I invoke `add` method of the `List` class from native code"_. It would involve getting the `java/util/List` class with `FindClass`, and its `add` method with `GetMethodID`. Then you need to create a `jstring` with `NewStringUTF`, add it to a `jobjectArray` created with `NewObjectArray`, and then calling the `List` `add` method with your `jobjectArray` as the argument. You might want to [read up on the available JNI functions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html).

Comment: thank you @Michael I will try to do it. just one question, I am dealing with windows-1256 encoded string, for the moment I am getting wierd symbols instead of arabic chars.. will that be solved with `NewStringUTF`? cause in java I wasn't able to view these chars in the logcat unless I used `new String (charArr, "WINDOWS-1256")`

Comment: and please **if you have the time** can you post an answer with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the sample code to set the boolean values, follow the same guideline to call the `add` method of the list.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include "com_example_Foo.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_Foo_someFunction
(JNIEnv *env, jobject object, jobject returnObject)
{
    jclass clzReturnObject = env->FindClass("com/example/ReturnObject");
    jfieldID fieldA = env->GetFieldID(clzReturnObject, "a", "Z");
    jfieldID fieldB = env->GetFieldID(clzReturnObject, "b", "Z");

    env->SetBooleanField(returnObject, fieldA, true);
    if (env->ExceptionCheck()) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error set boolean for a");
        env->ExceptionDescribe();
    }
    env->SetBooleanField(returnObject, fieldB, false);
    if (env->ExceptionCheck()) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error set boolean for b");
        env->ExceptionDescribe();
    }

    jfieldID fieldListID = env->GetFieldID(clzReturnObject, "list",
            "Ljava/util/List;");
    jobject listObject = env->GetObjectField(returnObject, fieldListID);

    jclass clzList = env->FindClass("java/util/List");
    jmethodID addMethodID = env->GetMethodID(clzList, "add",
            "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z");

    jclass clzString = env->FindClass("java/lang/String");

    jstring initElement = env->NewStringUTF("0000");

    jobjectArray toAdd = env->NewObjectArray(10, clzString, initElement);

    if (env->ExceptionCheck()) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error create string array");
        env->ExceptionDescribe();
    }

    env->CallBooleanMethod(listObject, addMethodID, toAdd);
    env->DeleteLocalRef(initElement);
}
```

Following is the java code

```
public class Foo {

static {
    System.loadLibrary("Foo");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ReturnObject returnObject = new ReturnObject();
    returnObject.list = new ArrayList<>();

    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.someFunction(returnObject);
    System.out.println("size is " + returnObject.list.size());

    foo.someFunction(returnObject);
    System.out.println("size is " + returnObject.list.size());

    foo.someFunction(returnObject);
    System.out.println("size is " + returnObject.list.size());

    // we have three element added from JNI
    for (String string : returnObject.list.get(2)) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}

public native void someFunction(ReturnObject returnObject);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @alijandro :) it worked. I will try to do the List function.

Comment: Thank you @alijandro so much  :) :) you have mega helped me. Just the last question, what should be modified to deal with `List<String> listA` add function?

Comment: You should change the `listObject` to `listA` and the added object `toAdd` to `jstring` type. @laurahelson

Comment: Thank you for the third time :) @alijandro

Comment: when I tested the code I was busy doing another task so I just tested the size of the List getting larger on the logcat. now I call the function multiple times the size of the list stays one and the output string when I execute `get(location)` is `[Ljava.lang.String;@4184e558`. am I doing anything wrong? @alijandro.. I know I disturbed you but its only been 4 months since I started learning :(

Comment: I made a small check, after the very last if statement I inserted `else` and the size of the list didnt increase so `env->ExceptionCheck()` is true

Comment: @laurahelson How did you do the operation? I have added some java code.

Comment: I've been trying for two days to do it, I thought I could ask you .. I need to call new String (char[], String encoding) from native code and have the result stored in a jsrting, is that possible?

Comment: @laurahelson Did you mean `new String(byte[], String)` constructor? sure, see the example I added.

Comment: @laurahelson If you think it's useful, could you vote for my answer? Anyway, it's a looong question.

Comment: I think It is very useful and I thank you so much but voting requires 15 reputation and im not there yet .. when I reach there I will definitely come here and vote

Comment: Thanks for this post. I was forgetting the semicolon in GetFieldID(clzReturnObject, "list", "Ljava/util/List;"); have an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to call string constructor to create jstring in JNI.

```
jbyteArray initValue = env->NewByteArray(10);
env->SetByteArrayRegion(initValue, 0, 9, (const signed char*)"ABCDEFG");
jstring enc = env->NewStringUTF("UTF-8");
jclass clzString = env->FindClass("java/lang/String");
jmethodID cMethodID = env->GetMethodID(clzString, "<init>", "([BLjava/lang/String;)V");
jstring result = reinterpret_cast<jstring>(env->NewObject(clzString, cMethodID, initValue, enc));
```

Comment: if the input instead of "ABCDEFG" is a char*, how is it represented?  @alijandro

Comment: char* p; (const unsigned char*) p; But i don't think it's a safe way.

Comment: may you please help me, I'm trying to set a java `String` from the native code, and also I want to read the value of `edittext.getchars().toString();` where edittext is a UI element.
Please help me I've been stuck for days on this @alijandro

Comment: when I add like 100 elements to the returnData list it crashes with this on the logcat,channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed. do you have any idea, I read it is because of memory overload? is there any way to prevent this  @alijandro

Comment: What's the details of the logcat output? Perhaps it runs out of memory, not very sure, never encounter such issue before.

Comment: the problem was that Java couldn't GC all these jobjects unless you tell jni to delete local ref of that particular jobject. and after that the heap or free space stack (not sure which) runs out of locations

Answer (score 0):

Following is an example to read the text of `EditText` from JNI.

```
void Java_com_example_foo_MainActivity_someFunction(JNIEnv* env, jobject object,
    jstring objString, jobject objEditText) {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "Foo", "%s\n", "JNI call");

    // get edittext value
    jclass clzEditText = env->GetObjectClass(objEditText);
    jmethodID methodGetText = env->GetMethodID(clzEditText, "getText", "()Landroid/text/Editable;");

    jobject objEditable = env->CallObjectMethod(objEditText, methodGetText);
    jclass clzEditable = env->GetObjectClass(objEditable);
    jmethodID methodToString = env->GetMethodID(clzEditable, "toString", "()Ljava/lang/String;");

    jstring editText = reinterpret_cast<jstring>(env->CallObjectMethod(
        objEditable, methodToString));

    jboolean isCopy = true;
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "Foo", "From java: %s\n", env->GetStringUTFChars(editText, &isCopy));
}
```

Assume there is a jni declared in your app's `MainActivity`.

```
private native void someFunction(String s, EditText editText);
```

I didn't find a good solution to set `String` from JNI directly. If you want to manipulate `String` in JNI, you could pass the result to Java from return value.

```
private native String Foo();
```

Comment: you provided me with many examples, I finally started figuring out the code my self.  @alijandro :)